# Typeface with curved vertical strokes?

Tags: fonts, typography, typefaces

Does anyone know of a typeface where the Capital "B" has a concave curve to the stem? (Where the vertical line dips curves inward to the right.)

Answer (score 1):

You find some easily - search for something which tries to look eastern, like this:

[image]

The screenshot is from [www.dafont.com](http://www.dafont.com)

I do not believe it's enjoyable to read long text passages written by using this or some other concave looking font. I suggest you to use something ordinary and if it must be concave, distort a short piece of text in Illustrator or other vector drawing program. An example (Illustrator, envelope distortion):

[image]

Comment: Nice, you found the first one. Sadly you did not include capital "B" in your example of a custom distorted text sample. The question was about fonts, and since you provided one, giving an extra work-around is a bonus. Welcome to graphicdesign!

Answer (score 0):

Since you are showing no visual example and give no context, we cannot know how intense you want this special feature to be. Or are you just trying to win a bet?

Here are some examples for you to look at; you should find all those on myfonts.com or similar sites:

Concavex™ by Ingrimayne Type

AZ Union by Artist of Design

Teutonic by Wooden Type Fonts

VLNL Bon Bon™ by VetteLetters

Tomato™ by Canada Type

What you want is rare. You will find many typefaces, where the left edge of the downstroke is clearly concave, but even with those, the right hand edge does not always follow or is less concave. See for example:

Arched Gothic Condensed SG™ by Spiece Graphics